# Spring NullPointerException with @Autowired Object with @EnableAspectJAutoProxy

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

i am new to spring framework and i am getting NullPointerException when i try to use the injected dependency. Here is my code:

DemoConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan("com.trial.classes")
public class DemoConfig {

}
```

AccountDAO:

```
@Component
public class AccountDAO {

    @Autowired
    TestClass test;    // the problem: the object is null!


}
```

TestClass:

```
@Component
public class TestClass {
    public void testMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("this is a test method");
    }

}
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DemoConfig.class);


    AccountDAO theAccountDAO = context.getBean("accountDAO", AccountDAO.class);

    theAccountDAO.test.testMethod();    //NullPointerException



        context.close();
    }
```

Comment: Don't use public/default use. Make the field private, and use a getter and it will work.

Comment: What is the package of all those classes? Post their complete code, from the first line to the last one.

Comment: Is this the package `com.Trial.classes` for `TestClass`?

Comment: all classes are within the same package: com.trial.classes

Comment: @EnableAspectJAutoProxy removing this annotation will work.

Comment: Your component scan is for `"com.Trial.classes"`, not `com.trial.classes`. Which is it?

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider i edited the question.. it is written correctly in my code.

Comment: @AnantGoswami removing EnableAspectJAutoProxy made the code work!! do you know why?

Comment: @Hussain Because EnableAspectJAutoProxy is AspectJ concept. It requires you to declare the pointcuts and aspects.

Comment: @M.Deinum it worked! but why? does dependency injection work only with getters and setters?

Comment: @AnantGoswami i am already declaring aspects. must be another reason.

Comment: @Hussain you didn't show in the question.

Comment: Because of proxies. Spring creates proxies for AOP. When doing direct field access you don't go to the real instance but the dummy proxy being created. Method calls will be, eventually, passed on to the real instance inside the proxy.